# J: Number of sign changes between items of list

Tags: arrays, list, j, tacit-programming, list-manipulation

Items of `a` are `_1` or `1`.

```
a =: 1 _1 _1 1 _1
```

There are 3 sign changes in `a`:

```
1, -1, -1, 1, -1
  Λ       Λ  Λ
 here   and here
```

How do I count them looplessly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You pair them with `2 v\`, check if they differ `~:/` and sum `+/`:

```
+/ 2 ~:/\ a
3

2 ~:/\ 1 1 1 _1 _1 _1 1 _1 1
0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1

+/2 ~:/\ 1 1 1 _1 _1 _1 1 _1 1
4
```

*edit*

Or you could line up the curtail `}:` and behead `}.` of `a` and compare them but that is notably less efficient.

```
+/(}: ~: }.) a
```

Comment: Could you explain why `+/@(}: ~: }.)` is less efficient than `+/@(2&(~:/\))`, please?

Comment: Mostly because `2 f/\y` is supported by [special code](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/release/infix2a.htm). One other thing is that beheading is expensive (both in time and space). It takes more to just behead a large `a` than to count the number of sign changes with the first way. You can make a large random `a` (`a =: 1 _1 {~ ? 1e6 $ 2`) and test it using `timespacex`.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, it is faster and cheaper. The fact that to code efficiently in J you need to remember all the SC is always putting me out, because it's like you say to J to do instruction `A` but J does `improved A` that is not what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

if the numbers can be other than 1 and _1,

```
  2 ~:&*/\ _2 4 3 _1 _3 1
1 0 1 0 1
```